# Splitting a separated string to a dictionary but ignore the "equal" between double quotes, in Python

Tags: python, string, dictionary, split

I have a string that looks like this:

```
'username-localhost-8888="2|1:0|10:1575303827|23:username=|f29abfba56b3dc1d"; _ga=GA1.1.497472408.1576657799; name=psqakwfmvw'
```

Is there a built-in function in Python that will take that string and construct a dictionary, as though to look like this(Which ignores the "compare" of double quotes):

```
dict = {
    "username-localhost-8888": "2|1:0|10:1575303827|23:username-44:ZTY2YjcyYTMyNDk2=|f29abfba56b3dc1d",
    "_ga": "GA1.1.497472408.1576657799",
    "name": "psqakwfmvw"
}
```

I have looked through the modules available but can't seem to find anything that matches.

Comment: Did you try *writing* anything? It looks like you want to split on semicolons, then on the *first* equals in each part.

Comment: Are you perhaps parsing a Cookie header? Context is everything.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with `.split`

```
input_str = 'username-localhost-8888="2|1:0|10:1575303827|23:username=|f29abfba56b3dc1d"; _ga=GA1.1.497472408.1576657799; name=psqakwfmvw'
output_dict = {}
# Note the space after `;`, this makes it so you don't get a space in the key
split_strings = input_str.split('; ')
for split_string in split_strings:
    # We only want to split once here since there can be multiple `=`
    key, value = split_string.split('=', maxsplit=1)
    output_dict[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be an easy task for `str.split()` and comprehensions:

```py
s='username-localhost-8888="2|1:0|10:1575303827|23:username=|f29abfba56b3dc1d"; _ga=GA1.1.497472408.1576657799; name=psqakwfmvw'
dict([x.strip().split('=', maxsplit=1) for x in s.split(';')])
```

And here is a proof of concept:

```py
Python 3.7.5 (default, Dec 15 2019, 17:54:26) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> s='username-localhost-8888="2|1:0|10:1575303827|23:username=|f29abfba56b3dc1d"; _ga=GA1.1.497472408.1576657799; name=psqakwfmvw'
>>> dict([x.strip().split('=', maxsplit=1) for x in s.split(';')])
{'username-localhost-8888': '"2|1:0|10:1575303827|23:username=|f29abfba56b3dc1d"', '_ga': 'GA1.1.497472408.1576657799', 'name': 'psqakwfmvw'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
output_dict = {}

str_data = 'username-localhost-8888="2|1:0|10:1575303827|23:username=|f29abfba56b3dc1d"; _ga=GA1.1.497472408.1576657799; name=psqakwfmvw'
list_data = str_data.split("; ")

for single_list_data in list_data:
    key, val = single_list_data.split("=", 1)
    output_dict[key] = val

print(output_dict)
```

Output:

```
{'username-localhost-8888': '"2|1:0|10:1575303827|23:username=|f29abfba56b3dc1d"', '_ga': 'GA1.1.497472408.1576657799', 'name': 'psqakwfmvw'}
```